# How much time update location in background mode

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, apple-maps

Actually, I'm litter bit confuse. I'm developing one App like driver and passenger. In the driver side if I start my drive by click on start button then the user will be move on apple map forget route direction.

When apple map will open at that time my App will be in background mode and Driver sending his/her current location to Passenger.

So question is that How much time we can send the current location to the passenger. As per my knowledge in iOS app will be alive 10 min. in Background mode. *(Not sure maybe)*

So how can I increase background time for keep alive the app background mode? Obesely there will be call API for send Driver current location to Passenger.

Comment: FYI : iOS app alive 3 minutes only in background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have background location updates enabled and "always" location permission and you have enabled location updates prior to your app entering the background then your app will continue to receive location updates indefinitely.

You only have a few seconds to process each update, but that should be plenty of time to send a short transaction to your server.

Comment: But we can call API in background mode even it is more then 10 minute ?

Comment: Yes.  Assuming you are using GPS-based navigation (ie "best" or "best for navigation) then you will receive location updates about once per second.  It is up to you how often you decide to send the location to the server; I would suggest once every 30 seconds or once every 250m is probably good, but it is up to you. Each time you send the data to your server it should only take a few seconds at most.  The updates you decide to ignore will take even less.